# Mysql retornar elemento de lista si no existe el ID

Tags: mysql, select, id

Tengo una lista de las que se emplean en un where in, por ejemplo:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Y tengo una tabla con un campo ID auto_increment. Mi objetivo es encontrar cuales son los elementos de la lista que no existen en el conjunto de IDs. Algo así como:

```
select Elemento from (1, 2, 3, 4) where Elemento not in (select ID from Tabla)
```

Cualquier forma de hacer esto me servirá (mientras funcione claro), y mientras más simple sea mejor.

Comment: ¿Que versión de MYSQL estás usando?  Lo digo porque parece que esto en mysql 8 te podria valer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587814/mysql-query-to-find-ids-from-a-list-that-dont-exist-in-a-table

Answer (score 1):

si te he entendido bien, seria asi de simple.

```
Select * from tabla where id not in (1,2,3,4);
```

si la tabla es

tabla

```
id | elemento 
1  | elemento1 
2  | elemento2
3  | elemento3
4  | elemento4
5  | elemento5
```

la select anterior nos devolveria

```
id | elemento
5  | elemento5
```

Comment: También se puede poner el not delante de id, '' Select * from tabla where not id in (1,2,3,4);

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta , puedes ser mas especifico para asi , de esta manera poder brindarte una solución

Comment: Gracias por responder. No, no es así, más bien sería lo contrario. En tu respuesta buscas los IDs que no existen en la lista. En mi caso lo que necesito es buscar los elementos de la lista que no existen en los IDs.